# Canvas image cropper - canvas.toDataURL is acting asynchronously does this return any kind of promise

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

If I put an alert between 'toDataURL' and a canvas draw using the result then everything proceeds as expected.

Does toDataURL fire an event on the canvas or should I use some kind of 'onLoad' for the image src I am setting it to?

IE img.addEventListener('load',function(){...}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.toDataURL` is a synchronous operation that does not trigger any events.

Being synchronous, it's a blocking operation so no `alert` is required to prevent the next command from executing before toDataURL is fully complete. The next command will execute when toDataURL is fully complete.

Since you're using the dataURL as an image source, you will want to give that image time to load by assigning a callback:

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
img.src=canvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: This is so strange though because that was my understand. Adding an alert after useing image.src = ...toDataURL allows the image to be written to another canvas while no alert writes nothing to the other canvas. Maybe it has something to do with using two separate functions?

Comment: Yes, you will want to attach an `image.onload=function(){ ...the image is fully loaded here... }` to your code.

Comment: Yep that worked! So then Im assuming image load, even when done programmatically, is an asynchronous event?

Comment: Yes, images are loaded asynchronously by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

> .toDataURL is a synchronous operation that does not trigger any events.
>   This is not true anymore for Chrome 57. Not sure if this is a bug or on purpose.

Comment: It's intended: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=514206