# make .each() wait for converting element to DataURL

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, html2canvas

I am using `html2canvas` for converting html2canvas,

I'm parsing html using `.each` and then pass elements to `html2canvas`. after element converted to `DataURL`. I push it to an array `content`.

```
$('.itinerary-section-detail').each(function( index, element ) { 
                 setTimeout(function() {
                   console.log(element);
                       html2canvas(element).then(function(canvas) {
                            element.appendChild(canvas);
                             elem  = canvas.toDataURL();
                              var item = {};
                              item["image"] = elem;
                              item["width"] = 595;
                              content.push(item);
                          }); 
                  }, 4000);
            });
```

but the issue is that time varies to convert an element to DataURL. that's why the order of elements are randomize. So I need to wait until an element get converted to `DataURL`, push it into `content` array   and then comes next element from `.each`.

Please suggest me a way here. Tried `setTimeout`, didn't work.

Comment: It seems that `.toDataURL()` is synchronous [toDataURL acting async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811253/canvas-image-cropper-canvas-todataurl-is-acting-asynchronously-does-this-retur)

Comment: what you can do is to increment a variable for each async launch (`html2canvas` I guess) and pass it to the callback, so that the element will know in which index it has to be put in the array

Comment: not trying to say it, I am actually saying it ;) added an example

Comment: I take it [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45949776/5053002) yesterday was useless?

Comment: @JaromandaX  It's not same as yesterday. this is about `.each` and inside it  
convert element to  `DataURL` and problem ordering elements

Comment: @JaromandaX Your answer worked for me indeed, I will accept that at the end of the day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just loop over asynchronous elements, because they don't pause loop. Instead you can construct array of promises and use [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/). Then a callback you provide will be called once all promises resolve:

```
var promises = $('.itinerary-section-detail').map(function(index, element) {
  console.log(element)
  return html2canvas(element).then(function(canvas) {
      element.appendChild(canvas)
      var elem = canvas.toDataURL()

      return {
        image: elem,
        width: 595
      }
    })
}).get()

$.when.apply(null, promises).then(function() {
  var content = [].slice.call(arguments)
  console.log(content)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, how can I push returned object to `content` array in `$.when`? Sorry for this question, I'm not aware of this all

Comment: still getting same result as `console.log('done', arguments);`

Comment: I meant as I've posted in question `var item = {};                          item["image"] = elem;  item["width"] = 595;                        content.push(item); how can I do this in `$.when` I'm  getting array of `ZoneAwarePromise`

Comment: You don't need to push anything, content array will be available in then callback as i posted in my answer.

Comment: `content` array shows `[ZoneAwarePromise, ZoneAwarePromise, ZoneAwarePromise, ZoneAwarePromise]` and I need `[{image:elem1,width:595},{image:elem2,width:595},{image:elem3,width:595}]`, how can I get this?

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153335/discussion-between-nikhil-radadiya-and-dfsq).

Comment: I have to add results from `content` to main `content` array, it doesn't add these results to main array

Answer (score 1):

this shows what i said in the comment. I simulated the async with a timeout and a random delay.

In the example, the IIFE is only used to keep track of `index` because it would be lost in the async callback (you can also wrap your async call in a function that stores the value)

results finish are not ordered, but the array result is.

```js
var content = [];

$('div.kadd').each(function( index, element ) { 
    console.log('launching: ' + element.innerHTML);
    (function(i){ setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('finishing: ' + element.innerHTML);
        content[i] = element.innerHTML;
    }, (Math.random() * 100) + 1); })(index);
});

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('result: ', content);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="kadd">A</div>
<div class="kadd">B</div>
<div class="kadd">C</div>
<div class="kadd">D</div>
<div class="kadd">E</div>
<div class="kadd">F</div>
<div class="kadd">G</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can't add `setTimeout()` as there can be too many elements. and this is one function I have more like same so need to do it same for all and using `setTimeout` will take too much time

Comment: the setTimeout is just an async example, in your case you'd just replace it by `html2canvas()`. It's true that my example is missing the code to know that all the async calls ended (which can be done with a promise, i used a global timeout instead). By the way, promise itself does not guarantee that results will arrive in order, that was the purpose of my answer, which only illustrates the ordered result